# SQL Selecting tables with month names from date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have tables named:

```
Posts_August_2011
Posts_September_2011
Posts_October_2011
Posts_November_2011
Posts_December_2011
Posts_January_2012
```

I want to create stored procedure that would `UNION` tables,but that is not the problem since I can use dynamic SQL to glue it up, my problem is getting Months and Year Range from RANGE to some kind of list? and then checking if table exist, Union them and return.

I would declare 2 variables `@FromDate` and `@Todate as datetime`

What would be the best way to extract month name and year for each of the months in given range.

Say I give it a range `@FromDate = '2011-10-18 14:16:27.000' and
@ToDate = '2012-01-09 14:16:27.000'` can someone advise how to extract Month and year.

```
DECLARE @SqlToExecute as nvarchar(MAX);
```

using dinamyc SQL is acceptable,It could check for existence of table in while loop and
glue to string for each table that exists in range as:

```
@SqlToExecute += 'SELECT * FROM Posts_' + extractedMonthName + '_' + extractedYear + ' UNION ALL ';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is caused by bad database design. You needed to store rows from all this tables in one table `Posts` with `date` field to specify Month and Year.

To get names of tables `Posts_%` and date extracted from their names you can use following code:

```
create table Posts_August_2011(i int)
GO
create table Posts_September_2011(i int)
GO

DECLARE @SqlToExecute varchar(max)
DECLARE @FromDate date = '20110801', @ToDate date = '20110809'

SELECT  name PostName, CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(name,'Posts_','01/'),'_','/') as date) PostDate
INTO #Posts
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name like 'Posts_%'

SET @SqlToExecute=''

SELECT @SqlToExecute += 'SELECT * FROM ' + PostName + ' UNION ALL '
FROM #Posts
WHERE PostDate>=@FromDate
      AND PostDate<@ToDate

SELECT SUBSTRING(@SqlToExecute,1, LEN(@SqlToExecute)-10)

DROP TABLE #Posts
DROP TABLE Posts_August_2011
DROP TABLE Posts_September_2011
```

[sys. tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx) is system catalog view which returns a row for each table object in the current database.

Comment: It is designed this way as custom partitioning and for easier management.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you I just did some adjustments,you last select was selecting LITERAL like first result in returned table was: SELECT * FROM foo UNION ALL.. I added:

SET @FinalToExec = SUBSTRING(@SqlToExecute,1, LEN(@SqlToExecute)-10)

DROP TABLE #Posts1

EXEC(@FinalToExec)

Comment: @user1010609 Thank you for reply. I am glad that I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATENAME(month,date)` and `YEAR(date)` to build your sets of months and years.

Easiest would be to create a tiny lookuptable that has year/month combinations and filter your date range, then just loop the results and build your query and execute.

For later you can look into partitioning that table into monthly partitions, if the size of the tables are what makes you split them like that.

Comment: Yea it is Im currently building SP to select them this way, the main reason for doing this is so I wouldn't have to union them all because of size

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to put these in a single [Post] table with post date?  And partition them if you need to?